# Getting user location takes a very long time inside Google Map FragmentActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity, locationmanager

I am having issues getting a location in my map activity. Basically, it gets the location, but takes a VERY long time (a few minutes). I'm using a singleton that requests a single location update to retrieve my location. This works fine across multiple other instances in my app. However when I try it in my map activity, it takes a very long time. Here is my class I use to get a location:

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

public interface LocationCallback {
    void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
}

public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //If network is available
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.i("SingleShot", "network available");
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()));
                }
                @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            }, null);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e("Location", "security exception");
        }
    }
    //If GPS is enabled
    else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Log.i("SingleShot", "GPS available");
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()));
                }
                @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            }, null);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e("SingleShot", "security exception");
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "No network or GPS available. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public static class GPSCoordinates {
    public float longitude = -1;
    public float latitude = -1;

    public GPSCoordinates(double lon, double lat) {
        longitude = (float) lon;
        latitude = (float) lat;
    }
}
}
```

This class works well in most areas in my app. It works in services and fragments. However when I use it in my map activity (FragmentActivity), the singleton takes a long time to use the callback I send it . Here is how I am requesting a new location from my map activity:

```
public class Traffic extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap map;
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(getApplicationContext(), new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                    Log.i(TAG, location.toString());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why this would be taking so long?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Criteria to COARSE or something which is less accurate but adequate.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html